# how to get first 'n' characters of a string

Tags: azure-logic-apps

**How do we get the first n characters of a string?**

I'm getting the following exception inside of Visual Studio when attempting the formula below:

[image]

I'm attempting to get the first `n` characters of a string, and using this formula:

```
take(body('Parse_JSON')[0]['subject'], length(body('Parse_JSON')[0]['subject'])-37)
```

The string looks like this:

```
WPS_case_export_1098897.xml_7efccd7a-4d11-4145-99b2-998162540a03
```

The result I'm looking for is:

```
WPS_case_export_1098897.xml
```

Here's quick overview of my steps:

[image]

**How do we get the first n characters of a string?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have oversimplified your query and well, the data set might include other files than the desired files but... Could you not do something as simple as this? I am using variables to declare and store the values desired.

[image: First(Split)]

My thought here is that 'xml' is always present and could be used as a delimiter in a split function.
[image: Result]

Comment: this is beautiful! i had no idea that split is able to take anything greater 1 character !!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with this monsterous solution:

```
last(split(substring(body('Parse_JSON')[0]['subject'],1,sub(lastIndexOf(body('Parse_JSON')[0]['subject'],'_'),1)),'/'))
```

Comment: however this is unfortunately ugly